# Wordpress same name page and directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have in root directory WordPress and my URL's looks as 
https://example.com/page/posts

But my directories (csgo, tf2) have same names as pages in WordPress.

```
...
wordpress/
├── csgo/
│   ├── banlist/
│
├── tf2/
│   ├── banlist/
...
```

I need when call url .../csgo/**banlist** then redirect to folder ../csgo/banlist

and next problem is, when call url .../csgo/ then loading directory, not wordpress page.

But i don't know how to solved my problem.
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**

in **main** WordPress **.htaccess** comment out (#):

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

and in your directory (in my solution is it - .../csgo/**banlist**)
put files: **index.php** and **.htaccess**.

Paste code into the file **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_wordpress/csgo/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my_wordpress/csgo/banlist/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and now works url /csgo/ (wordpress page) and /csgo/banlist (directory)